# How to fetch next 10 SQS messages after fetching first 10 SQS messages at any point in time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I am trying to develop a UI for the QA team where they can check queue messages without logging into AWS.

I'm just displaying the first ten queue messages in this UI to keep costs down, but what if the QA person needs to fetch further records after reviewing the queue messages?

How can I fetch the next 10 messages from queue without using the visibility timeout option?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may want to temporarily write your SQS messages to a database at the same time and have the QA team view messages in the database instead. SQS has no concept of paging or 'next 10' - when you read messages from the queue you are supposed to process and delete them - and then ask for more. Browsing database records maybe better for QA purposes.

Comment: Ya that's a good idea .. Any ways I used "10 messages" because the max batch size to fetch messesge from Queue is 10 ... Thanks E.J

Answer (score 2):

If you want more messages, just ask SQS for more messages.

SQS knows that *somebody* already got the first 10, but it has no idea that it was you.  If you ask for more, you'll get more.

Until the visibility timer -- which is 30 seconds by default -- expires on messages you received, you can repeatedly ask and ask and ask and you will not see the same messages again.  The messages are "in flight" -- meaning that SQS is waiting for someone to delete them, modify their visibility, or for the timer to expire.  Once the timer expires, you'll start seeing them again.

Each SQS queue allows up to 120,000 messages to be fetched without acknowledgement, deletion, or visibility change.  Good luck hitting that limit.

---

> i cant use visibility time out as product is in production and my tools should not block actual service from consuming queue msgs

I'm not sure exactly what that means.  If you are saying that your queue has a default visibility timeout of 0, then the real problem here is that you're doing it wrong to begin with.  A default visibility timeout of 0 will result in duplicate message delivery if you have more than one consumer.

Review the documentation for [visibility timeout](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AboutVT.html).  Visibility timeout is how long the consumer is allowed to hold the message without deleting it or changing its visibility timeout *before it will be delivered to another consumer*.  It does not delay the availability of messages that have not yet been consumed, or of messages that have been consumed and whose timeout has elapsed or been reset.

If you want to inspect messages without blocking the application, fetch them from the queue, sending as many requests as you need (making more than one request, if more than 10) and then immediately send an API request to set the visibility timeout to 0 for those messages.  This will immediately release them to be consumed again, by the application (or by this tool, if the application is backlogged, of course).

---

Alternative: for a truly independent path for analysis of queue messages, I use a different approach: SNS Fanout.

Instead of the message producer sending messages into SQS directly, I send them to an SNS topic.  The primary queue and a secondary queue are both subscribers to this topic.  The application consumes from the primary queue, and the secondary queue just sits there collecting a second copy of each message.  When messages expire from the secondary queue, they just disappear (default = 4 days).  This gives me a very useful tool for troubleshooting as well as for handling anything catastrophic in the application consumer that results in improper message handling, where messages received from SQS were subsequently lost due to unexpected or unhandled conditions.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. but i cant use visibility time out as product is in production and my tools should not block actual service from consuming queue msgs.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to delete the first 10 messages otherwise they will keep being returned. It's possible that even a deleted message may be returned so it's important your system be able to handle duplicate messages.